# How to prove that $f(x)=|x|$ is not surjective?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f(x)=|x|$. How to prove that $f$ is not surjective?

---

I need some help with this exercise.

Suppose $f$ is surjective.
Be $a\in\mathbb{R}$ , $\exists\;b\in\mathbb{R} $ such that $f(b)=a$, well. i consider two cases.

Case 1: $b>0$, then $f(b)=b=a$

Case 2: $b<0$, then $f(b)=-b=a\Rightarrow b=-a$ Okay, in this case i have a problem because i didnt see the contradiction, can someone help me?

Comment: $|x|\geq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, right? So no negative number is in the range of $f$.

Comment: okay @carmichael561 then the contradiction is in $b=-a$?

Comment: Yep. @FlybyNight sorry

Comment: Don't be afraid to give a *specific* counterexample, as in Jack's answer. To show that a function is not surjective, it is enough to show a *single* element of the range that the function cannot reach.

Comment: The key issue here is that you've focused on the input, $b$, rather than the output, $a$ of the function. You can't arrive at a contradiction because there *are* some $a \in \Bbb R$ that are the output of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cases should depend on the sign of $a$, since for a given $a$ you're trying to find $b$ such that $f(b)=a$.

If $a\geq 0$ then taking $b=a$ gives $f(b)=a$.

But if $a<0$ then there is no $b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|b|=a<0$. Indeed, if $b\geq 0$ then $|b|=b\geq 0$, and if $b<0$ then $|b|=-b>0$. In both cases $|b|$ is non-negative, so cannot be equal to $a$.

Answer (score 6):

You are making things complicated. Look at the definition of "surjective" again:

> A function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is surjective if (and only if) for **every** $y\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=y$.

There is *no* $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=-1$.